# The 'X' button when voting to close isn't centered

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

If you click 'close' on a post, the X in the button to close the popup isn't centered in the circle:

[image]

OS X 10.6.8, Chrome 20.0.1132.57

Answer (score 1):

The fix is now on Dev. Will be rolled out to production after the next nightly build.